# WP7 HttpWebRequest without caching

Tags: caching, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

It seems that HttpWebRequest caching in WP7 is enabled by default, how do I turn it off? 
Adding a random
 param  url + "?param=" + RND.Next(10000) works, but it's quite tricky and I'm not sure if it will work
 with all servers.

Comment: Found a problem for this issue using the HttpWebRequest object? current provided answer are all server side solutions. (except for the time stamp, which i don't like)

Comment: Btw, a good parameter is DateTime.Now.Ticks. It will always change and its size is acceptable (at least for the first couple of decades :-))

Answer (score 19):

For future reference , this worked for me ( I could not use additional query parameter due to project requirements) :

```
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        if (request.Headers == null)
        {
            request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
        }
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```

Comment: @Agent_L the request looks different for the WP7 HTTP client

Answer (score 11):

In case of **HttpClient** (Portable for Windows Phone) "Cache-Control": "no-cache" on server side works only sometimes. And I cannot add query string random value to RESTful api call as well.

Solution from @frno works good and looks like for HttpClient:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This was the only method that works for me as well. The other cache headers seem to have no effect.

Comment: Very good solution, also for Windows 8.1 Store Universal apps.

Comment: This was working for us, now its throwing 304s from time to time.

Answer (score 6):

How do you know it's the phone, not the server (or a proxy somewhere between) which is caching?
Have you checked this with Fiddler2 (or equivalent)?

Have you tried setting headers to disable caching?
Something like:

```
myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);

myRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
myRequest.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
```

Comment: It's not the server, because same url updates corectly on BlackBerry,IPhone and Android

Comment: I ran into this issue with ReSTful end-point I was developing for a WP7 app.  Changing the server to ensure it returns a response with the "Cache-Control" header set to "no-cache" resolved this issue.

Comment: I just had this problem, and for me, adding the headers (Cache-Control=no-cache and Pragma=no-cache) solved the problem. I did realize this is the client (WebRequest) that caches the response (turned off web server and get request would still return the cached result).

Answer (score 1):

We've seen the same behaviour with Silverlight hosted in Chrome.

We add a `"?nocache=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()` to our request URLs if we want to prevent caching.

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 ways

1. Add a random Query String to the end of your URI (think Guid.NewGuid()) this will avoid caching on the client as the Query String will be different each time

> string uri = "http://host.com/path?cache="+Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

2. Specify no cache in the OutgoingResponse header within your WCF service operation:

> ```
> var __request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
> if (__request.Headers == null)
>     __request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
> __request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
> ```

3. markup your service operation with the AspNetCacheProfile attribute:

> ```
> [AspNetCacheProfile("GetContent")]  
> public ResultABC GetContent(string abc)  
> {  
>   __request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(abc);
>   return __request;  
> }
> ```

And update your web.config

> ```
> <system.web>  
> <caching>  
>      <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" />  
>      <outputCacheSettings>   
>         <outputCacheProfiles >   
>             <add name="GetContent" duration="0" noStore="true" location="Client" varyByParam="" enabled="true"/>   
>         </outputCacheProfiles>   
>     </outputCacheSettings>  
> </caching>  
> ...  
> </system.web>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding random number is not bad and it will work. I have used Time (in ajax call). Was placed in the url like a folder.

Comment: yes it works for now, but I'm not satisfied with this, and I'm looking for better solution

Comment: with random number you could get the same number but with time ( like ms since midnight - 1 to 86 400 000) it almost impossible. you can even combine these two. have you tried with POST?

Answer (score -2):

Yes is possible... :) I spend one week of Experiment and the answer is really simple :

```
      HttpWebRequest _webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(_currentUrl);

     _webRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false
 _webRequest.BeginGetResponse(_onDownload,
 userState);
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem + throws internal exception "not supported".