# Refreshing a page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to refresh a page in wp7. Searched in google and get this

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));
```

but when I am using this there is an error, ie the application breaks.

How can I refresh the current page in wp7?

Comment: Just wondering why you are refeshing rather than using INotifyPropertyChanged on your objects / Observablecollection<>s?  I can think of a couple of valid use cases, but was wondering...

Comment: For example, I used this because an initially collapsed panorama item could not be made visible without messing up the layout of the panorama, so I had to "reload" the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just provide a unique URL ID and it will reload the same page. You can generate a random number, but the easiest way is probably with a GUID.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format(NavigationService.Source +
                                    "?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Comment: Sir i am just facing an issue to reload the same page but with new web response data in ListBox. Actually i am having situation where there are lot many list data, so i have to load the same page but with new list data related to that clicked item. Yes pages are navigating fine, but ListBox data is not getting refreshed because web call is not achieving. Can you please give your time?

Comment: You should post this as a new question. How is your ListBox data being set? (Databinding using INotifyPropertyChanged?) and what exception is thrown in your web call, and are you using WebClient or HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @PareshMayani - If your requests are being cached, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching

Comment: @keyboardP yes i am getting web response successfully every time, the problem i was facing is not able to load same page with new response data, now what i did? I am just making a new web call based on every list item click. Thanks much for the reply.

Comment: @keyboardP i am making web call by using WebClient. What problem i am facing now is: "Having ListBox in screen, clicking on any item its fetching data from web and fill up it, same process for List item click but the problem is if i coming back from level 4 to level 2 and if i click on any list item at level 2, it will react item click in Level 4", i guess ListBox doesn't come to know that data is being changed. I have actually maintained a List<List<Object> so while coming back, i get data from this data stack list and binding to the ListBox.

Comment: @PareshMayani - Using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a List can be better because the `ObservableCollection` will automatically tell the Listbox to update and refresh the contents. But I'll have to see the listbox code to figure out what the issue could be. Post a new question with the details and maybe I, or someone else, will know what the issue is :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri( "/Game.xaml?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative) );
```