# Trouble with async webrequest

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

In my first page I launch an async webrequest on page loaded event.

```
 Private Sub LoadRecent()
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("")
        request.Method = "GET"

        request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ResponseRecent), request)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ResponseRecent(ByVal asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
        Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)
        Dim webResponse As HttpWebResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult)
        Dim stream As New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseString = stream.ReadToEnd

    End Sub
```

Using this code, `Loadrecent()` is successfull launched on page loaded. Let's suppose I have a button in the first page that brings me in another page. If I press Back button I am brought to the first page again and the `Loadrecent()` is fired as well.
The problem is that the response of the webrequest is the same of the first time it have been fired (and I can tell you this is not possible). It's just like I should dispose the async webrequest after I made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

[WP7 HttpWebRequest without caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching)

It suggests that you modify the headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probobly just caching as a workaround make your call unique set a timestamp or a random number at the end of your url and you'll get diffrent results.