# Why GET method called one after another replicates first answer?

Tags: windows-phone-7, get

I have problem with Get method on Windows Phone. When I do Get method I receive some answer and then I do post method which changes the answer of the get method and then I check once again doing get method but still it gives me the same answer from first Get (somehow it has been replicating the Get answer from the first method). 
How can I change it?

Sample code of Get Method:

```
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLS.host);
        wr.Method = "GET";
        wr.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        wr.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallbackListaStrategii), wr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a caching issue. Assuming you have not control, or don't want to, change the server side response you could try adding a random query string each call and see if that fixes it. For example, set your `URLS.host` value to be:

```
URLS.host = String.Format("{0}&rnd={1}", URLS.host, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLS.host);
```

Alternatively, you could try the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching).

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
if (request.Headers == null)
{
   request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
}
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wr.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
wr.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
```