# Query fetching Old Data Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform

My WP8 app is fetching old data instead of updated data when I run the query:

```
private async Task fetchParseData()
{
    try
    {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Favorite")
          .WhereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username);
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

        this.favorites.Clear();

        foreach (ParseObject result in results)
        {
            string venue = result.Get<string>("venue");
            string address = result.Get<string>("address");
            string likes = result.Get<string>("likes");
            string price = result.Get<string>("price");
            string contact = result.Get<string>("contact");
            this.favorites.Add(new ItemViewModel { LineOne = venue, LineTwo = address, LineThree = likes, Rating = "", Hours = "", Contact = contact, Price = price, Latitude = "", Longitude = "" });

        }

        if (favorites.Count == 0)
        {
            //   emailPanorama.DefaultItem = emailPanorama.Items[1];
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have any saved cafes. Long press a cafe in main menu to save it.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data could not be fetched!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me find where the problem is in this query. I debugged and found error in only this part. SO, my new data is not being fetched by the `query.findasync()` method.

Comment: Is your data store in ISO (isolated storage) of windows phone in application domain; or you are fetching data from web request using http?

Comment: From the web using Parse SDK

Comment: make sure that your data is update one, I did not find any culprit code line in your code snippet.

Comment: Yeah m pretty sure because i see updated data in my Parse data browser but not in WP view

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phones Web Cache is quite aggressive.

If the servier you are querying from does not explicitly set a cache-duration in the http headers, windows phone will cache all requests (don't know the duration though, but pretty long).

You can:

1. Set the "Cache-Control: no-cache" Header on your server.
2. Add a random number (or timestamp) to each request so the uri differs.
3. Try add the "if-modified-since" header to your requests.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching) for details.

Comment: I can't set the headers as this is not my server. It is Parse.com. It offers Mobile Backend as a Service. (MBaaS).

Comment: In that case you have to add a random get param to your requests query string.